# wicket Exception starting filter wicket

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, wicket

I'm trying to create a web application using wicket. These are the steps I've followed :

1. I created a maven project using this command :

   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=6.6.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/ -DinteractiveMode=false
2. I imported the project to eclipse
3. I enabled Maven Dependancies with right click
4. I converted my project to a web project and set a Tomcat 7 server
5. By right click I ran the project on this server, producing the message: `HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.`

This the error message on the console :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter wicket.myproject
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Now here is my pom.xml :

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.amadeus
    RDA_2
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
        
    quickstart

```
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.6.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.3.v20120416</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-devutils</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                        <port>8443</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
                        <password>wicket</password>
                        <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Apache Nexus</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

And here is my web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.myproject</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.WicketApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket.myproject</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone help me please ????

Comment: try running `mvn install`, refresh the workspace, then run tomcat again. sometimes, with some versions of m2e, Eclipse doesn't get the jars until you run the build manually.

Comment: See my comment on the answer below. Try running without eclipse in the way, you might be better of ditching eclipse all together ;)

Comment: @tetsuo After running mvn install i have this error from JUnit : wicket.Initializer cannot be cast to org.apache.wicket.IInitializer

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but here is what solved the problem:

Right click on project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly

Be sure that the libraries of the project are deployed into the WEB-INF/lib folder. In my case there were no libraries at all, so I had to add them by pressing

Add -> Java Build Path Entries

And selecting the libraries (wicket libraries among those)

Comment: Or add the "Maven Dependencies" Lib, that helped me.

Comment: Adding on Deployment Assembly Maven Dependencies work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your POM? This class belongs to `wicket-core`, the quickstart added this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check that this declaration is in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I checked my pom.xml i have it.

Comment: @enzo Can you update the question including your `pom.xml` and `web.xml`?

Comment: try building the project with maven (mnv clean package) and deploy (copy to the webapp folder) in a tomcat. i suspect eclipse is doing something stupid here, so eliminate this source of problems first

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro : I ve included the two files you asked for

Comment: Why do you have the second wicket dependency, version 1.2.7? Please remove this dependency and build again.

Comment: Fernando is right, remove the wicket:wicket:1.2.7 dependency, it may be creating some kind of classpath conflict.

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro I ve removed the 1.2.7 version, now i ve no error with JUnit. but even this i ve still the HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available when run my project in server. That s the URL im using : http://localhost:8080/myproject/

Comment: OK, some progress. The URL seems ok, so I do not think that this is the problem. Can you update (or even put on a gist) the stack trace? Also, the log when you start the server will be useful, as it points which application and context path it is using.

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro : i ve updated my question with the stack trace. help please :) ???

Comment: @enzo I only see the stack trace for the original error, not for the `HTTP Status 404: requested resource is not available`. Please post the logs from initialization in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/). Or, is it possible to send us you project as a zip file? I think it is only a test project. Send through dropbox or any other service.